# How is this functional form derived?

Tags: calculus

In the book "probability theory: the logic of science", the following statement is made:

[image]

**My question is: How do they conclude from $\frac {\delta G(x,y)G(y,z)}{\delta y}=0 $ that the above functional relation for $G(x,y)$ must hold?**

(I've tried to figure it out myself to no avail)